# iproute2 commands for MPLS configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, routes, netlink, iproute

Trying to figure out how one can use iproute2 to manage static label-switched MPLS routes in Linux kernel 4.1.

I am aware iproute2 support for MPLS might be incomplete right now [2].

Can anyone please shed some light on what iproute2-4.1.1 is currently able to do?

This is what I have found so far:

### Documentation/networking/mpls-sysctl.txt

/proc/sys/net/mpls/platform_labels 
/proc/sys/net/mpls/conf//input

### Load mpls module

```
sudo modprobe mpls_router
```

### Find sysctl support

```
sysctl -a --pattern mpls 
net.mpls.conf.eth0.input = 0 
net.mpls.conf.eth1.input = 0 
net.mpls.conf.lo.input = 0 
net.mpls.platform_labels = 0
```

### Enable mpls support

```
sudo sysctl -w net.mpls.conf.eth0.input=1 
sudo sysctl -w net.mpls.conf.eth1.input=1 
sudo sysctl -w net.mpls.platform_labels=1000
```

### push??? (how to add prefix-to-push action?)

```
sudo ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via mpls 100/200/300 dev eth0
```

### swap??? (how to add label-swap action?)

```
sudo ip -f mpls route add 10 via mpls 100/200/300 dev eth0
```

### pop??? (how to add label-pop action?)

???

### show??? (how to display label-switched routes?)

???

Can someone help me out .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A little bit too late, but hope it helps somebody. You can find them [here](http://pieknywidok.blogspot.com.es/2015/12/mpls-testbed-on-ubuntu-linux-with.html):

Routing 10.10.10.10/32 to 192.168.1.2 with label 100:

```
ip route add 10.10.10.10/32 encap mpls 100 via inet 192.168.1.2
```

Label swapping 100 for 200 and sent to 192.168.2.2:

```
ip -f mpls route add 100 as 200 via inet 192.168.2.2
```

Decapsulating label 300 and delivering locally:

```
ip -f mpls route add 300 dev lo
```

To show MPLS routes you can do:

```
ip -f mpls route show
```

If your iproute2 version doesn't support those commands, you can get it from here:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/iproute2-4.6.0.tar.gz

And then

```
./configure && make && make install
```