# MPLS in mininet using iproute2, RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, mininet

I am trying to use MPLS on mininet I was able to install iproute2 and when I try something like this

```
ip route add 192.168.10.187/32 encap mpls 101 via 10.10.0.187
```

I get the error:

```
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "encap" is a garbage.
```

Also when I try something like this

```
ip -f mpls route add 101 dev lo
```

I get the error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I checked my config file and set all of this, with no success:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
```

I have the linux image 4.4.0-97-generic, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After doing some reading I found out that I am missing the directory /proc/sys/net/mpls

**UPDATE 2**

After doing more digging somehow, don't ask me how, I finally installed the missing module and now I have this error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

**UPDATE 3**

I still have the previous problem stated in UPDATE 2, but I noticed when I try to add a new route, I get no complains and it actually shows on the routing table. However when I do:

```
ip -f mpls route show
```

I get no results

Comment: The `ENOTSUP` message typically comes because the module is not available in the kernel. No mention of the MPLS modules in that config (they're `MPLS_` variables). on the presumption that they're compiled as loadable modules, try loading the routing module using `modprobe mpls_routing`

Comment: @Petesh I tried that and I got this message: `modprobe: FATAL: Module mpls_routing not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-97-generic`

Comment: you seem to have found the module. There is a pretty good answer here for all the commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926342/iproute2-commands-for-mpls-configuration

Comment: @Petesh thanks I was actually reading that post and it works when I add a route but the show command doesn't show anything and I get the same error when trying to uncapsulate or swap labels

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to load the kernel mpls modules first,

```
modprobe mpls_router
modprobe mpls_iptunnel
```

Then, allow the network interfaces to process mpls labeled packets (disabled by default)

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/mpls/conf/IFNAME/input
```

(where IFNAME is the name of the network interface that will send/receive mpls packets)

And finally, specify number of entries that the kernel should allocate for labels (0 by default)

```
echo 2048 > /proc/sys/net/mpls/platform_labels
```

or else the iproute2 will gladly process your routes but the kernel won't know any of them (I've been bit by that, too).

References:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/mpls-sysctl.txt
- http://www.samrussell.nz/2015/12/mpls-testbed-on-ubuntu-linux-with.html